# Truncated field is being returned from view

Tags: mysql

I have a view in MySql (5.7.30) that is composed using a `GROUP_CONCAT`statement. The field is rather long as it aggregates several rows of data.

The problem I'm facing is that the row only returns around 1000 characters of the `transaction_details_html` field and truncates off the rest.

Is it possible for me to return the entire string? Or is this a hard limitation?

The view looks like this:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`10.132.93.224` 
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
VIEW `paid_transactions_email_zapier` AS
    SELECT 
        `t`.`id` AS `id`,
        `t`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
        `t`.`date` AS `date`,
        `t`.`payment_provider_code` AS `payment_provider_code`,
        `t`.`payment_tx_id` AS `payment_tx_id`,
        `t`.`status` AS `status`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<tr style="height: 30px;">',
                    '<td align="left"><a href="https://myapp.com/',
                    `d`.`id`,
                    '">',
                    `c`.`title`,
                    '</a></td>',
                    '<td align="left" style="padding-left: 10px;">',
                    `td`.`product_id`,
                    '</td>',
                    '<td align="left" style="padding-left: 10px;">',
                    `d`.`language_name`,
                    '</td>',
                    '<td align="right" style="padding-left: 10px;">$',
                    `td`.`price`,
                    '</td>',
                    '</tr>')
            SEPARATOR '                        ') AS `transaction_details_html`,
        SUM(`td`.`price`) AS `total_price`,
        `u`.`email` AS `email`,
        `up`.`fname` AS `fname`,
        `up`.`lname` AS `lname`
    FROM
        (((((`transaction` `t`
        JOIN `transaction_detail` `td`)
        JOIN `user` `u`)
        JOIN `user_profile` `up`)
        JOIN `distribution` `d`)
        JOIN `content` `c`)
    WHERE
        ((`td`.`transaction_id` = `t`.`id`)
            AND (`u`.`id` = `t`.`user_id`)
            AND (`up`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`)
            AND (`d`.`id` = `td`.`distribution_id`)
            AND (`c`.`id` = `d`.`content_id`))
    GROUP BY `t`.`id`
    ORDER BY `t`.`date` DESC
    LIMIT 100
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global variable  `group_concat_max_len`  determines how big GROUP_CONCAT can be. usually it is 1024 characters, so your number is strange

You can increase, so that your query runs without hickups.

Like

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 10000;
```

Comment: Ah! Yes, sorry my number was actually wrong. I was looking at the "column" number and not the overall character count in my editor. Your solution worked like a charm